# Is there a way to make dynamic apex field references bind a reference to the fields?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dynamic-soql

Is there a way to make dynamic apex field references bind a reference to the fields? To illustrate the question, let's take the following example query:

```
String query = "SELECT myField__c FROM Account"
Database.query(query);
```

In the example, the field myField__c is not strongly referenced. This means you can delete the field from SFDC (without getting a field deletion prevention error stating what it's tied to) and blow up the apex next time the query is run.

I'm looking for a way to prevent the deletion of a field called out in a dynamic query (in this example: myfield__c) while still maintaining the dynamic referencing aspect of the query.

Obviously, if the following apex existed in a class somewhere, the system would give an error if someone tried to delete myfield__c from the Account object:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT myfield__c FROM Account];
```

But I would like to prevent deletion of the field when myfield__c is referenced like so:

```
String query = "SELECT myField__c FROM Account"
Database.query(query);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely you can. Just merge in strings that you build from `SObjectField`. I would recommend using `String.join`. Simple example:

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>
{
    String.valueOf(Account.MyField__c),
    String.valueOf(Account.OtherField__c)
};
Database.query('SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' FROM Account');
```

Comment: That works, but it defeats the purpose of dynamic.

Comment: How does it defeat the purpose... you've given very little detail in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dummy method to keep a solid reference:

```
public static void keepReference() {
  Object[] fields = new Object[] {
    Account.MyField__c, Account.MyOtherField__c
  };
}
```

Personally, I'd advise against using dynamic queries if you can help it, since they are inherently fragile. Dynamic queries should be considered a last resort.